# Filter hierarchy

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, hierarchy, hierarchical-data

I'm writing an application with Core Data that have to maintain a catalog with 4 levels of hierarchy.

```
Category <--->> SubCategory <--->> Item <--->> SubItem
```

I have a screen (table/collection view) where `Items` are displayed along with `Category` and `SubCategory` titles. The Items could be.
Basically I have to display filtered catalog. Let's say Item have a name and I want to filter items by name.

Example.

```
Category: Category 1
  SubCategory: SubCategory 1.1
    Items: [aaa, bbb, ccc, abc, abd, abg] 
  SubCategory: SubCategory 1.2
    Items: [aaa, bbb, ccc] 
Category: Category 2
  SubCategory: SubCategory 2.1
    Items: [123ab, 456ab, 123, 345, 456]
```

After filtering with query 'ab' I want to see the following objects:

```
Category: Category 1
  SubCategory: SubCategory 1.1
    Items: [abc, abd, abg] 
Category: Category 2
  SubCategory: SubCategory 2.1
    Items: [123ab, 456ab]
```

The thing is: I can't use fetch request against `Category` because it will only show me categories that contain items that satisfy criteria but it will not filter items.
I can directly fetch filtered collection of `Item` but I have to rebuild structure `Category - SubCategory - Item` and put it in some arrays/dictionaries etc.

Is there a better way to filter deeply nested hierarchy with CoreData?
The main question: is there a way to fetch leafs of deeply nested object tree while running fetch request against its root?

Comment: I am having a hard time understanding the criteria with which you want to filter the Items. could you expand a little bit more on how the subitem affect the fetch request

Comment: Added example & updated description.

Comment: Can you post the `fetch request` you used to filter?

Answer (score 0):

You can filter `items` using `searchString` by,

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]initWithEntityName:@"Item"];
NSPredicate *predicate = nil;

 if([_searchBar.text length] > 0){
    predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"itemName CONTAINS[cd] %@", _searchBar.text];
}

if(predicate){
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
}

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]initWithKey:@"itemName" ascending:YES];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];
```

If you need to sort the result by considering `category` and `subCategory`, you can use more sort descriptors according to your priority like,

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptorCategory = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]initWithKey:@"categoryName" ascending:YES];
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptorSubCategory = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]initWithKey:@"subCategoryName" ascending:YES];
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptorItem = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]initWithKey:@"itemName" ascending:YES];

[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortDescriptorCategory, sortDescriptorSubCategory, sortDescriptorItem, nil]];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just separate each key with a **'.'** like so...

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptorSubCategory = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]initWithKey:@"Category.SubCategory.Items" ascending:YES];
```

then, in iOS 7 +

```
[YOUR_ARRAY sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sortDescriptorSubCategory]];
```

Or, older iOS versions

```
[YOUR_ARRAY sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray sortDescriptorSubCategory, nil]];
```